# Temperature Data Software

Tags: climate-change, climate, temperature, mapping, climate-data

I'm looking to create a map of the U.S. that depicts mean winter and summer temperatures. Is there a software suitable for this?

I found CSVs of data here: https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/normals-daily/2006-2020/access/

But it is not easy to understand the format, or to plot it.

Comment: My first thought was GrADS, but it's more for making contours, and usually using data in a different (gridded) format.  To plot simple csv, I'd think Python/Cartopy would work quite well, or [GIS applications](https://guides.library.duke.edu/QGIS/ImportData) (you'd need shape files for the US too).  Though you'd have to download all the data files and average the three months you want.  So it's going to take a while using any of these methods.

Comment: It may well be a lot quicker if you want a contoured plot (rather than individual values) to use the [NCEP reanalysis page](https://psl.noaa.gov/data/composites/day/)... you can quickly average a range of dates (you'd want 2m temp).  And then there's an option to download the results as netcdf once you plot it, where you could clean it up for how you want to display it (probably convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit)

Comment: I, as many, hesitate with the dangers of AI code writing to our world... yet we can't deny how it can be amazingly efficient at times. Using Bing's Chat and the prompt "Write python code to get a list of all files at https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/normals-daily/2006-2020/access/
Then download all those station data files
Then average the csv data inside those files by season
Then plot the results using cartopy" gave me pretty remarkably decent results (though you'd to maybe redefine seasons, and work out a few small bugs + become familiar with Python). We're going to be obsolete soon?!?

Comment: AI usage seems a lot like search engines or calculators/computers probably were in previous generations... many held onto the way things were done, but being able to use these tools PROPERLY will be a huge life skill that will allow those adept to blow away their peers.  But that means learning how to craft good input (just as important in Googling or calculators!) and to be able to judge how valid the output is/understand it, which does take a lot of learning.  Whereas using it to blindly give answers will only lead to lack of ability in the long run when it comes time to make money :-)